# Searching a Word Document from Excel - v2.0

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

My first question:

[Searching a Word Document from Excel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62668/searching-a-word-document-from-excel)

Since then I have implemented most of the suggestions by @RubberDuck and @Comintern. I have also added functionality for different-sized spreadsheets (horizontal and vertical), read multiple files in during a single run of the macro, and a bunch of constants.

This is what I currently have:

```
Global lineCount As Integer

Sub LoadWordFromExcel()

    Const ONE As Integer = 1
    Const FIRST_ROW As Integer = 2
    Const PATH_TO_FOLDER As String = "C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\Macro folder\"
    Const LAST_NAME As Integer = 3
    Const CHOP_LEFT As Integer = 21
    Const CHOP_RIGHT As Integer = 11

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim c As Integer        
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ActiveSheet

    'Finds last row and column with valid data
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(ONE, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    For c = ONE To lastColumn
        file = Dir$(PATH_TO_FOLDER & sheet.Cells(ONE, c).Value & ".docx")
        If (Len(file) > 0) Then
            filePath = PATH_TO_FOLDER & file
            Dim entries As Scripting.Dictionary
            Set entries = LoadWordToDictionary(filePath)
            For r = FIRST_ROW To lastRow
                For k = 1 To lineCount
                    If InStr(entries(k), sheet.Cells(r, LAST_NAME).Value) <> 0 Then
                        sheet.Cells(r, c).Value = Left(Right(entries(k), CHOP_LEFT), CHOP_RIGHT)
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        sheet.Cells(r, c).Value = ""
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox ("I'm Finished")
End Sub

'Loads data from word document and adds it to a dictionary
Private Function LoadWordToDictionary(file As String) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim host As New Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim lines() As String

    'loads data from Word doc into lines'
    Set doc = host.Documents.Open(file)
    lines = Split(doc.Content.Text, vbCr)
    doc.Close
    host.Quit

    Dim output As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim items() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'Loads data from lines(array) to output(scripting.dictionary)
    For i = 0 To UBound(lines)
        Call output.Add(i + 1, lines(i))
    Next i

    lineCount = UBound(lines)
    Set LoadWordToDictionary = output

End Function
```

Questions:

1. Am I still unwittingly using Hungarian Notation? I read the article but it brought up more questions than answers.
2. Is there anything that I'm overthinking and could simplify? I'm looking at my nested `for` loop and can't help but think there's another way to do it.

So far, this script is FAST. It can enter over 5,000 cells of information in under 30s instead of the 5-10 minutes for 300 cells that the first version did.

Comment: I'll move the two questions over there then. And right now the whole thing works as long as the word document closed properly before the program ran. The issue really only came up when I was testing it and it terminated early.

Comment: With the edits you made I think this is now on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answers

**Question 1:** No, this is now Hungarian-free™. The [article that was referred to in your prior post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) differentiated between "Apps Hungarian" and "Systems Hungarian", and your previous code was using the latter (i.e. `strName`). You were basically indicating that your`Function SearchWordDoc(strPath, strName)`was expecting `String`'s as parameters. The current code is both more explicit and will in fact not even compile if you try to pass it anything but a `String`. This is a Good Thing™.

**Question 2:** This one is harder to answer without some information about the layout of the spreadsheet. From the code, I would gather that row 1 consists of column headings that correspond to your Word document names and that column "C" is the last names that you are looking up. If this is the case, your first loop (the "c" loop) counter is off - instead of starting at 1, it should start at the first column that is expected to have a value. I'm not sure exactly what the inner-most loop (the "k" loop) is doing - it seems to rely on the Word document being in the same sort order as the rows in the spreadsheet.  The `Dictionary` key is an integer, and you're using the row as the key when you index it instead of the last name. Take a another look at [my answer to your last post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/62996/36565), you should be parsing a name out of the Word file for the `Dictionary` keys.

### Other Observations

**Finding Worksheet Size:** The following code will likely return inconsistent results in many cases (at least it does for me):

```
'Finds last row and column with valid data
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(ONE, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

Excel's `Worksheet` object [has a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732%28v=office.15%29.aspx) that is much easier to use and much more reliable and readable in your code:

```
With sheet.UsedRange
    lastColumn = .Columns.Count
    lastRow = .Rows.Count
End With
```

**Using ActiveSheet:** Don't do it. After you get your reference to sheet at the start of `Sub LoadWordFromExcel()`, don't use `ActiveSheet` again. If you need a reference in another function, pass it as an argument. Within the same function, always use your captured reference. To expand on my answer to your previous question, every time you call `ActiveSheet`, you get a reference to whatever `Worksheet` Excel has active.  If you are half way through your routine and the user opens another workbook, your reference can change.  This can (and will) result in read garbage cells and writing into the wrong spreadsheet.

**Global Variables (other than constants):** Avoid them in any way that you can, as they can lead to unexpected and hard to locate bugs. Variables should always have the minimum required scope.  In your case, you are using `lineCount` to track how many items you add to the `Dictionary` object you return, but there isn't a reason to do this.  You can just get a count directly from the object:

```
'instead of 1 To lineCount ...
For k = 1 To entries.Count 
    ...
Next
```

**Constants:** Definately well intentioned, but there are a couple of things to mention here.  First, these should typically be placed in your module's header (after the missing `Option Explicit`). The primary reason to do so is so that they get a wider scope. Remember, the goal of having a constant is not just to have an easily identifiable name - it make changes a lot easier. For example, if your layout changes, you can change `Const LAST_NAME As Integer = 3` to whatever value you need exactly once instead of searching all over for the number 3 and trying to figure out if it is being used as a column index. That said, `Const ONE As Integer = 1` is *never* going to change. Use `1` instead. The other goal, easily identifiable names, is the other place I would make a couple minor changes to make them more explicit and readable.  I'd likely do something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const FIRST_DATA_ROW As Integer = 2
Private Const WORD_DOCUMENT_PATH As String = "C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\Macro folder\"
Private Const LAST_NAME_COL As Integer = 3
Private Const PARSE_START_INDEX As Integer = 21
Private Const PARSE_LENGTH As Integer = 11
```

**Variable Names:** While you can occasionally use one letter loop counters like `i` when it is obvious that you are indexing something, in this case it would be better to be more descriptive in what you are looping through and how you are using the loop counters to index.  This is much more important in nested loops than in a simple array traversal.  I'd suggest something more like this:

```
Dim row As Integer
Dim key As Integer
Dim col As Integer

For col = 1 To lastColumn
    ...
    For row = FIRST_DATA_ROW To lastRow
        For key = 1 To entries.Count
            ...
        Next key
    Next row
Next col
```

I'm also a fan of the `Next [Variable]` syntax for readability, especially with nested loops.

**Odds and Ends:** The following If test will never return False:

```
file = Dir$(PATH_TO_FOLDER & sheet.Cells(ONE, c).Value & ".docx")
If (Len(file) > 0) Then
```

The length of the `file` variable will always be at least `5 + Len(PATH_TO_FOLDER)` - it can never be zero. You should also make a habit of using `Trim$()` before you test a string length (unless you care about white-space).

Also, if you are going to return a the value of `Left()` or `Right()` into a `String`, use the string specific functions `Left$()` and `Right$()` to prevent casting back and forth from a `Variant`. Better than `Left$(Right$(var, start), length)` would be to use the `Mid$()` function.

This test is wildly inefficient:

```
If InStr(entries(k), sheet.Cells(r, LAST_NAME).Value) <> 0 Then
```

It takes the returned `Item` from the `Dictionary` and then uses a string comparision to see if it matches the cell contents. The `Dictionary` object has [a method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hdf10z%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to determine if a given key exists - `.Exists()`. Restructuring this one If statement can likely eliminate the inner-most loop entirely (assuming you key by name).

```
Dim key As String
...
key = Trim$(sheet.Cells(row, LAST_NAME).Value)
If entries.Exists(key) Then
    sheet.Cells(row, col).Value = Mid$(entries(key), PARSE_START_INDEX, PARSE_LENGTH)
Else
    sheet.Cells(row, col).Value = vbNullString
End If
```

Finally (and this is more of a pet-peeve of mine), use the built-in constants when they exist to improve readability. `""` is much harder to comprehend at a glance than `vbNullString` in much the same way that `vbCr` is easier to read than `Chr$(13)`.

Comment: I stumbled across [an article](http://www.shamrock-software.eu/vb.htm) this morning while trying to figure out exactly how your suggestions work. It's interesting to see the difference in speed between using mid and mid$, even if it is a 10 million loop operation.

Comment: Also, in regards to Mid, I needed to cut the text from the right side of the string because it was a constant length. If I tried to do it from the left side my results would have gotten jacked up by people with different names.

Comment: Sorry for all the consecutive comments. I'm looking at the `.Exists()` portion now. I don't think your method would work because it only returns `True` or `False` and not the location of the string I'm searching for. I'll keep playing with it, but so far it seems a lot slower than using my clunky `Instr` search

Comment: @slow_excellence - Regarding `Mid$()`, it is pretty easy to calculate a string offset for your starting index using the length of the string. `Len()` is cheaper than `Left$()` - `Mid$(target, Len(target)-charsfromleft, length)`. To your first comment, the String functions are faster because they don't need to be cast back and forth to a Variant type.

Comment: @slow_excellence - The `.Exists()` function tells you if the key is in the dictionary or not. Since you are trying to match names, making the name the key allows you to retrieve it. That is how it allows you to dispense with the inner-most loop (you don't have to check every value in the collection for matches). Think of a key-value pair of "Smith, John"-#1/1/14#. You need the date for "Smith, John", so you pull it directly from the Dictionary by key (`entries("Smith, John")`). The test `.Exists(key)` makes sure that the retrieval from the key returns a value.